# Given $l$ points in unit $n$-sphere, expectation of smallest radial distance

Tags: expectation

Consider the unit $n$-sphere and $l$ points distributed uniformly randomly inside its hypervolume. What is the expectation of the smallest distance from a point to the sphere centre?

Steps done so far are:
Find distribution function of distance from random point to zero:
$P(\xi < x) = x^n$, and the distribution function of the closest to zero point is $P(\xi < x) = 1 - (1-x^n)^l$. Then considering E(x) = $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x \cdot d(F(x))$, the problem is how to calculate it.

Comment: It cannot be true that $X_k\sim U(-1,1)$ for each $k$ if the point is restricted inside the unit ball.

Comment: Thank you, fixed this.

Comment: well, but still you have to tell how the $l$ points are distributed on the ball: uniform on the spherical coordinates $\rho,\theta\phi$ ?

Comment: $$E(\xi)=\int_0^1P(\xi>x)dx=\int_0^1(1-x^n)^\ell dx=\int_0^1(1-t)^\ell \frac1nt^{1/n-1}dt=\frac1n\mathrm{B}\left(\ell+1,\frac1n\right)$$ where $\mathrm B$ denotes the Beta numbers, defined as $$\mathrm{B}(u,v)=\frac{\Gamma(u)\Gamma(v)}{\Gamma(u+v)}$$

Comment: The points are uniformly distributed over the interior of an n-dimensional hypersphere of radius 1 centered at the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cdf of the random variable describing the distance $r$ from a random point in the unit $n$-sphere to the centre is $r^n$, so the pdf is its derivative or $nr^{n-1}$. Now we are looking for the first order statistic of a sample of $l$ points from this distribution, whose pdf computes to (using the formula given on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrderStatistic.html))
$$l(1-r^n)^{l-1}nr^{n-1}$$
Thus the desired expectation is
$$E(n,l)=\int_0^1rl(1-r^n)^{l-1}nr^{n-1}\,dr$$
Substitute $s=r^n$:
$$=l\int_0^1s^{1/n}(1-s)^{l-1}\,ds=l\mathrm B\left(1+\frac1n,l\right)=\frac{l\Gamma(1+1/n)\Gamma(l)}{\Gamma(1+1/n+l)}=\frac{l!}{\prod_{i=0}^{l-1}(1+1/n+i)}$$
$$E(n,l)=\prod_{i=1}^l\frac i{1/n+i}$$